# How to merge 2 condition into 1 line of SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

I tried using AND but it didn't work
This is the original code

```
getAllFeeds(user_id_fk, start) {
  let data = [user_id_fk, start]

// ---------this part here ------------------------------------------------------------
  return this.database.executeSql("SELECT * FROM feed WHERE (user_id_fk) = (?) ORDER BY feed_id DESC LIMIT ?, 5", data).then((data) => {
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    

  let feeds = [];
    if (data.rows.length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
        feeds.push({ feed_id: data.rows.item(i).feed_id, feed: data.rows.item(i).feed, user_id_fk: data.rows.item(i).user_id_fk, created: data.rows.item(i).created });
      }
    }
    return feeds;
  }, err => {
    console.log('Error: ', err);
    return [];
  });
}
```

How do I add this?

```
SELECT DATETIME(created, '+8 hours') as `add8hours` FROM feed WHERE (user_id_fk) = (?) ORDER BY feed_id DESC;
```

When I use this last line the result will only show the date time and not the other columns
This is the table BTW

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS feed (
feed_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
feed TEXT,
user_id_fk INTEGER,
created DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Comment: `AND` should work. How did you try? Could you show?
And yes, on the last Query you choosed (SELECT) only colmn `created`, not `*`, which shows all columns

Comment: SELECT DATETIME(created, '+8 hours') as `add8hours` AND feed FROM feed WHERE (user_id_fk) = (?) ORDER BY feed_id DESC LIMIT ?, 5"

Comment: The second query only shows a subset of all records.  In your final result do you still want to show all records?

Comment: yes please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show some specific columns from a table, you need to separate them by a comma.
Eg (using aliases): `SELECT COLUMN_1_NAME as ALIAS_COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2_NAME as ALIAS_COLUMN_2 FROM TABLE_NAME;`

So in your case it should be something like:

```
SELECT DATETIME(created, '+8 hours') as add8hours, feed FROM feed WHERE (user_id_fk) = (?) ORDER BY feed_id DESC LIMIT ?, 5
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help